# UINavigationController adds auto padding to the left of the pushed view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios13

I Have two viewControllers. One is home page, other is detail page. if I make them window's root view controller they look like this:
This is My Home Page

[image: Home Page]
This is my details page

[image: Detail Page]

but when I make my home page my root view controller and push my detail view controller to present, it looks like this :

[image: Pushed detail view Controller]

So here is my detailviewController. It has one scrollview and uistackview. no storyboard used.

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

let scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
    let view = UIStackView()

    view.axis = .vertical

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

and this is the constraints:

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)

scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)

scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
// this is important for scrolling
scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

I think it is iOS 13 related problem.

EDIT: If I make animated to false when pushing detailvc, everything is normal.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is really in constraints, try to set `scrollView` - `widthAnchor` equal to `view` width and `centerXAnchor` equal to `view` center X.

It seems to me wrong to set the following at the same time:

```
scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

and

```
scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

I suggest leaving the last constraint and also align the `scrollViewContainer` in the centerX relative to the view.

I hope it will help you.